# Passing List objects through Braid

Tags: cordite

I try to invoke a flow through Braid. The flow takes a `List<UniqueIdentifier>` object as input parameter. When invoking the flow I get the following error:

`error: -32000: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier`

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I'm no expert, but you're probably passing it a `LinkedHashMap` where it expects a `UniqueIdentifier`. If we could see the code around the error, that would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deserialisation error of Braid. It might get fixed in a future version. A workaround at the moment is to use Array objects instead of List objects in Corda.

Useful functions are:

```
List.toTypedArray()
```

and

```
Array.asList()
```